# How do you obtain the itemId to upload a file into BIM 360?

Tags: .net, autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/upload-files-bim-360-c

Following this tutorial, how do you obtain the itemId in the **4. Create version** section? Since you can only get the itemId if an item already exists inside the folder. Am I wrong or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From following the code in the link below, I am able to create a new item if it doesn't exist inside the folder or create a new version if it does.

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/data.management-csharp-sample/blob/b3ab49a41f6e20161d0c5d707f2e56bc7e3e27ad/forgeSample/Controllers/DataManagementController.cs#L324

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can only get the exiting itemId from Hubs->Projects->Folders->Items, the tutorial of https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/ mentioned the way to create a 1st version of item, or update a new version of existing item. And also check at  http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/datamanagement/hubs/readme for the details and code sample to get the item.